# redirect in facebook canvas app

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom, facebook-canvas

Is it possible to do page redirects in canvas app?
I was reading facebook's tutorial and I am seeing this:

> Note that http://www.example.com/canvas cannot forward to another URL via HTTP redirect responses, for example response code 301, but has to return the response directly.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/) says with this is that you should not have your first page that loads in the canvas, which is referenced here as `http://www.example.com/canvas`, send a `301 redirect` to some another page. You should render and send first page, or `http://www.example.com/canvas`, and then, if your situation requires redirects then you may do the same.

Answer (score 0):

While the initial canvas page cannot return a 301 response, you can have the loaded page do a redirect via javascript.